# How to comparing existing data in mysql in a more efficient way?

Tags: php

I have written a PHP web spider to get news title from a website.
When I get the title, I will insert them into mysql.
It really works when the first time.
However, the jobs will run every hour.
But later, I don't want to insert the duplicate data.
So, I need to check every time when I insert to mysql.
But I think it is not a good way to do so.
Any better ideas?

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: You can use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a number of things:

- Change your table to be unique on the title field. It won't allow duplicate entries.
- Make the table unique on the title and date fields - this will allow duplicates, but not in the same day - this will help allow you to enter in news articles with the same name (they might appear and *should* be there.
- run some SQL first to see if the data is already there, and it it is, don't insert it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a unique Key to automatically decide which articles should be classed as duplicates.

Take the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news_items(
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    create_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX UK_title_create_datetime (title, create_datetime)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

This table has a unique key on title and the create_datetime.
The following insert statement would match items on that key and ignore them without throwing an error or inserting duplicated.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO news_items (title, create_datetime, description) VALUES ('My News Item', '2012-08-30 11:35:00', 'Something newsworthy happened');
```

You could easily update the selected fields for matching rows too using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO news_items (title, create_datetime, description) VALUES ('My News Item', '2012-08-30 11:35:00', 'Something newsworthy happened')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    description = VALUES(description);
```

Have a look at MySQL's [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) documentation and [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)